# MySQL Access denied for user 'User'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, database, jsp, netbeans

I connected a MySQL database for a project (java web application) in netbeans. I created MySQL server with correct login details as root and created a database. I connected my database to the project, but when I am running the application it was showing error in the browser as:

```
type Exception report

message Internal Server Error

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'User'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'User'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1 logs.
```

Entry in the log file is:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'User'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:925)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1704)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1250)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2465)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2498)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2283)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:822)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at org.apache.jsp.Login_jsp.cn(Login_jsp.java:114)
    at org.apache.jsp.Login_jsp._jspService(Login_jsp.java:589)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
```

I am tired in few ways as mentioned in some other forms but not use.

Comment: You didn't have user with name `User` exists and if it exists then User account is not password protected. First try connecting DB with UN and PW you are using in your code.

Comment: @Naman . User is created surely because when I see in mysql list of users it is showing that name also.

Comment: Have you tried login in mysql using that UN(User) & PW(your PW)?

Comment: @Naman yes, but i is showing error as ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'User'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: You must have entering wrong password for user.

Comment: @Naman .. should I have to give root password for the User also? I used statement like this GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname.* TO 'User'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'Pass' WITH GRANT OPTION;

Comment: Are you using `Pass` as password right?

Comment: @Naman yes i am using Pass as password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution,  When I was using sql statement for grant privileges i used

```
'user@%'
```

because of that it was not working. Correct sql statement was:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname.* TO 'User'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Pass' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't create the user `'bkUser'@'localhost'` correctly.

Comment: i created correctly by using the following sql statment: <br/><pre> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname.* TO 'User'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'Pass' WITH GRANT OPTION; </pre>

Comment: MySQL doesn't agree with you. You got at least the password wrong.